# Node.js + express + cors not working: pending options requests

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I tried about 10 different options but I cant get my POST request start working instead i have options request that is pending and never completes

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Accept');

  // intercept OPTIONS method
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.send(200);
  } else {
      next();
  }
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.options('*', cors());

app.use(require('./routes/order-templates.js'));
app.use(require('./routes/statuses.js'));
app.use(require('./routes/fields.js'));
app.use(require('./routes/users.js'));
app.use(require('./routes/groups.js'));
app.use(require('./routes/upload.js'));
app.use(require('./routes/feedback.js'));

app.use(require('./routes/order.js'));

app.use(express.static('public'));

var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/ior';

mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});

app.get('*', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Fired at ' + Date());
});
```

**users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var User = require('../model/user.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

var cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://188.225.82.166:3000/',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
}

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.options('/users/auth/', cors(corsOptions))
app.post('/users/auth/', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({"mail": req.body.mail, "password": req.body.password}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (user == undefined) {
            res.send({"result": "error" })
            res.sendStatus(200)
        } else {
            res.send({"result": "ok", "_id": user._id, "type": user.type })
        }
    });
})

module.exports = app
```

If I do

```
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('After CORS ' + req.method + ' ' + req.url);
    next();
});
```

in **server.js** I get

```
After CORS GET /
After CORS GET /bundle.js
After CORS GET /bootstrap.css.map
After CORS GET /favicon.ico
```

And nothing prints in console after post requests is triggered.
Also worth mentioning the fact, that the problem exists only when I deploy to server with ubuntu. Locally on mac os machine everything is fine

Comment: I can't see any reason for the OPTIONS request to hang. The line `app.use(cors());` that you have near the top of `server.js` should be enough all by itself, you should be able to get rid of all the other CORS-related code. If you change the top of `server.js` to this https://jsfiddle.net/fjL7oejo/ you should get some logging to see what's happening. The OPTIONS request should only trigger the first bit of logging, other requests should hit both. If you still can't figure out what the problem is it might help to show us exactly what request you're doing when it fails.

Comment: updated the post with logging details and some additional info

Comment: Same issue here can't find any solutions. Did you manage to get through this ?

Comment: I don’t remember exactly,  I think the problem was with some server setup, outside cors and express.

Comment: I have opposite problem on MacOS with nodejs and express 4. Options response is fine with cors but subsequent response for POST request does not include 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Answer (score 8):

You should use cors before bodyParser and allow it for PUT/DELETE also.

```
// Add cors
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());  // enable pre-flight
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 5):

It may be helpful for others like me:
In the beginning I thougth it is the server side problem, but then the reason of cors error became my frontend. I was sending requests to `localhost:3000/api` instead of `http://localhost:3000/api`
That's it

Comment: Spent hours on this... Thanks.

Comment: So glad I saw this - it's one of those "duh" mistakes that you can spend hours trying to fix

Comment: Same issue with me, Thanks @Almas Kamitov for pointing out solution.

Answer (score 1):

For others like me scratching head for 2hrs trying to fix the POST cors issue, please also double check the options of your POST request.

For me it was a small typo of **header: {...}** instead of **header(*s*): {...}** in the POST options, the express server configured using cors allowing all origins responded with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" restricted error.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was looking around for hours and this was my issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In you user.js file use router.post instead of app.post.

```
router.post('/users/auth/', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({"mail": req.body.mail, "password": req.body.password}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (user == undefined) {
            res.send({"result": "error" })
            res.sendStatus(200)
        } else {
            res.send({"result": "ok", "_id": user._id, "type": user.type })
        }
    });
})
```

Then export router module

```
module.exports = router;
```

Also i would suggest to use bodyparser in server.js file. So you don't need to use it in every file.

Answer (score 0):

After applying "cors" middleware. You should append "http://" before "localhost:". in URL

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/getData")
.then(function (response) {
this.items= response.data;
}).catch(function (error) {
console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the trailing slash in `origin`.